# Insert text at the cursor position to a CKEditor using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I'm trying to add a piece of text to an existing CKEditor using jQuery.
This needs to be done when a link is clicked.

I tried this solution, which works for regular textareas, but not for CKEditor:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  insertAtCaret: function(myValue) {
    return this.each(function(i) {
      if (document.selection) {
        //For browsers like Internet Explorer
        this.focus();
        sel = document.selection.createRange();
        sel.text = myValue;
        this.focus();
      } else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
        //For browsers like Firefox and Webkit based
        var startPos = this.selectionStart;
        var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
        var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
        this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos) + myValue + this.value.substring(endPos, this.value.length);
        this.focus();
        this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
        this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
        this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
      } else {
        this.value += myValue;
        this.focus();
      }
    })
  }
});
```

There is also an option to use: `$('#editor').val()`, but this appends the text at the end or the beginning and not at the cursor.

So, is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You should use this

```
$.fn.insertAtCaret = function (myValue) {
    myValue = myValue.trim();
    CKEDITOR.instances['idofeditor'].insertText(myValue);
};
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!
I made a slight change: `CKEDITOR.instances[$(this).attr("id")].insertText(myValue);` so I don't need to worry about the id.

Comment: This has changed in CKEditor v5 - See [How to insert some content into the editor?](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/examples/how-tos.html#how-to-insert-some-content-into-the-editor)

Answer (score 19):

CKEditor itself has a mechanism to insert text. If you update the `textarea` directly you are in effect bypassing some of the mechanisms CKEditor has to keep track of what text has been entered. Try this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.IDofEditor.insertText('some text here');
```

[More information here](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=15555)

Comment: you are the king

Answer (score 4):

I thought I should mention that if you are using the jQuery adapter for ckeditor you can insert text with jQuery this way which looks a little cleaner.

```
$('textarea#id_body').ckeditor().editor.insertText('some text here');
```

or if you are inserting HTML

```
$('textarea#id_body').ckeditor().editor.insertHtml('<a href="#">text</a>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar.  I am using CKEditor 3.6(due to budget), JQuery and Bootstrap.  I wanted a list of buttons that would insert some text when clicked into the body of the CKeditor.  I created a list of buttons from my data elements then added a click event.  My object is an input button with a data attribute that I read to get the val to paste.

.insertText("texthere") will give you the actions you need to put the value where the cursor is in the body.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".dataelement").click(function () {
          InsertDataElement($(this).data("valtxt"));
      });
});
function InsertDataElement(valtxt) {
    CKEDITOR.instances['FullDescription'].insertText(valtxt);
}
```