# CKEditor.NET Append via jQuery

Tags: c#, ckeditor, webforms, ckeditor.net

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224075/insert-text-at-the-cursor-position-to-a-ckeditor-using-jquery) on this and am trying to simply add text via jQuery into my CKEditor.  I am using this code but it gives the following error:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    CKEDITOR.instances.txtDESCRIPTION.insertText('some text here');
});

---

<%@ Register TagPrefix="CKEditor" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" Assembly="CKEditor.NET" %>
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl id="txtDESCRIPTION" Toolbar="SplendidCRM" Language='<%# Session["USER_SETTINGS/CULTURE"] %>'  Height="400" BasePath="~/ckeditor/" FilebrowserUploadUrl="../ckeditor/upload.aspx" FilebrowserBrowseUrl="../Images/Popup.aspx" FilebrowserWindowWidth="640" FilebrowserWindowHeight="480" runat="server" />
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertText' of undefined

How can I simply add the text "test" to my CKEditor?

Note:  This uses CKEditor.NET, not the jQuery CKEditor version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is result of a bug in CKEditor as documented here http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/6497.  As a workaround, I simply append text on button click like so:

```
$('#myBtn').click(function(){
    CKEDITOR.instances._ctl0_cntBody_ctlEditView_txtDESCRIPTION.insertText('some text here');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you called `CKEDITOR.replace('txtDESCRIPTION')` yet?

if so then `oEditor.setData('test')` should do the trick.

Edit:

it appears that ckeditor.net is renaming the id

from the [link](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/CKEditor-replace-fails-.Net-FormView) in the comment bellow

> You can get around the problem of controls being renamed by finding
>   the ClientID of the control. I put code in the codebehind to find the
>   control's ID and set Javascript for it. That way the code is not
>   affected by rearranging controls on the form. If there is more than
>   one editor instance on a form, simply call InsertEditorJS for each
>   one.
>
> Here is the codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox qiiEditor = (TextBox) FormView1.FindControl("qiiTextBox");
    Literal qiiJS = (Literal) FormView1.FindControl("qiiTextBoxJavascript");
    InsertEditorJS(qiiEditor, qiiJS);
}
protected void InsertEditorJS(TextBox TextBoxCtl, Literal LiteralCtl)
{
    LiteralCtl.Text = "<script type='Text/javascript'>";
    LiteralCtl.Text += "CKEDITOR.replace('";
    LiteralCtl.Text += TextBoxCtl.ClientID;
    LiteralCtl.Text += "');</script>";
}
```

Comment: When I call that it says, "`Uncaught [CKEDITOR.editor.replace] The element with id or name "txtDESCRIPTION" was not found. `"

Comment: it appears that ckeditor.net is renaming the id. check this post out.
http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/CKEditor-replace-fails-.Net-FormView

Comment: I found in the code that `.replace` is already being called.  I am trying to use the ID that it uses (generated by .NET) `CKEDITOR.instances._ctl0_cntBody_ctlEditView_txtDESCRIPTION.insertText('some text here');` but it still gives me an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'insertText' of undefined "

Comment: try putting a breakpoint before you call to insert text and see what is inside of instances

Comment: It doesn't not tell me anything is inside of it.  But, the editor works so I know the generated code must be working: `CKEditor_Init.push(function(){if(typeof CKEDITOR.instances['_ctl0_cntBody_ctlEditView_txtDESCRIPTION']!='undefined' || !document.getElementById('_ctl0_cntBody_ctlEditView_txtDESCRIPTION')) return;CKEDITOR.replace('_ctl0_cntBody_ctlEditView_txtDESCRIPTION',{"filebrowserBrowseUrl" : "../Images/Popup.aspx", "filebrowserUploadUrl" : "../ckeditor/upload.aspx", "height" : "400", "htmlEncodeOutput" : true, "language" : "en-us", "toolbar" : "SplendidCRM"}); });`

Comment: I think this is a CKEditor error.  See http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/6497 The code will work via a button click but not on `document.ready()`.